# How to find the length of a path given coordinates of start and end node in networkx?

Tags: python, networkx, geopandas

Hi does anyone know how to find the distance from a certain node to a certain node?

test.json files contains all the coordinates, but not sure how to find the total distance of the path if I was given the start and end node.

I wanted to divide the path if the total meters from the starting point to the end point is more than 10 meter.

for example
(A-B-C-D) if A to C is more than 10meter, then I would like to have 2 different path such as A-B and C-D.

Following is how I create the graph taken from json files. If I have used the wrong way, could you please let comment on it :D

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import momepy
import networkx as nx
roads = geopandas.read_file(r"c:\users\cyntha\downloads\files.json")
roads=roads.explode(index_parts=True)

G = momepy.gdf_to_nx(roads, approach="primal")

positions = {n: [n[0], n[1]] for n in list(G.nodes)}

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6), sharex=True, sharey=True)
roads.plot(color="k", ax=ax[0], aspect=1)
for i, facet in enumerate(ax):
    facet.set_title(("pipes", "Graph")[i])
    facet.axis("off")
networkx.draw(G, positions, ax=ax[1], node_size=5)
plt.show()

print(f"IsConnected: {nx.is_connected(G)}")

print(f"Number Connected Components: {nx.number_connected_components(G)}")
for cc in nx.connected_components(G):
    print(cc)
```

[image]

files.json looks like this :

```json
{"type":"FeatureCollection", "features": [
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[282403.3563000001,6136123.1767],[282409.9263000004,6136121.7267]]},"properties":{"id":"1"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[282495.41619999986,6136048.4667],[282500.0362,6136044.2067],[282496.2762000002,6136034.1167]]},"properties":{"id":"2"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[282521.23620000016,6136007.3567],[282521.1462000003,6135973.1367],[282520.9762000004,6135966.5167]]},"properties":{"id":"3"}}]}
..
```

Comment: sorry for that. Changed :)

Comment: From what is provided it is difficult to answer your question. Please include a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") containing both data, and code that can be copied and pasted along with a clear description of what is wrong with your current effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`shortest_path_length(graph, source, target)`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path_length.html) to evaluate the length of the shortest path from `source` to `target`. The function will raise a `NetworkXNoPath` error if no path from `source` to `target` exists.